# Select range of cells and save to new document

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select cells in a sheet and export them to a new document.

The sheet has multiple columns, however I want to select only the columns from C to E, from the forth row to the last row that is not blank in column E.

The code that I've written is the following:

```
Sub SelectExcelCopy()
Dim appWD As New Word.Application
appWD.Visible = True
Range("C4", Range("E4").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    appWD.Documents.Add
    appWD.Selection.Paste
    appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="File 1"
    appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
appWD.Quit
End Sub
```

The code works as intended in a new excel sheet (only for testing purposes), but in my current workbook it does not.
The sheet in my current workbook is filled with a lot of data from column A to column C. Even though in column E there are only two entries (E4 and E5), the table in the word document has 44 columns and 134 rows.

I've verified the sheet and the cells in the E column are blank, except the ones that I want them in the table.

What change should I make to the code in order to achieve my purpose?
Thank you!

Comment: You are selecting the range wrong. You need to set a last row variable and use something like this... `Range("A1:D" & lRow).Copy` don't use column D in your last row variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is simple example:

```
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

Sheet1.Range("C4:E" & lRow).Copy
```

Comment: Thank you! This formula still gets me more rows than the actual rows that are not blank. It generates me 3 pages of rows (78 empty rows). And the idea of my plan was to select the last row variable from the last column.

Comment: You don't want all the data from column C, just the data to the last used cell in column E, is that right?

Comment: Exactly. For example, C and D have 10 rows, and E has 4 rows. I want the code to select and copy the range from C1 to E4.

Comment: @MarianV. Change the lRow variable to `Rows.Count, 5`, it will select the last used cell in column E.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the importance of the 'Rows.Count'. It now works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: @MarianV. glad to help.